# ipkg can't install tcpdump

Tags: linux, router, repository, tcpdump

I have the new Asus Blue Cave router with a USB drive mounted at `/mnt/DRIVE`.  I installed `ipkg` via a GUI-based install of their Download Manager.  I am trying to `ipkg install tcpdump`.

I have `mount -o loop /mnt/DRIVE/opt /opt` after installing `ipkg`.

`# find / -name ipkg.conf`:

```
/tmp/mnt/DRIVE/asusware.mipsbig/etc/ipkg.conf
/tmp/mnt/DRIVE/opt/etc/ipkg.conf
```

I have added a new repository with `tcpdump` package.

`# cat /tmp/mnt/DRIVE/asusware.mipsbig/etc/ipkg.conf`:

```
#Uncomment the following line for native packages feed (if any)
#src/gz optware.asus http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/ASUSWRT
src/gz optware.asus http://nw-dlcdnet.asus.com/asusware/mipsbig/stable
src grc http://www.cobb.uk.net/openwrt/
dest /opt /
#option verbose-wget
```

`ipkg list` shows `tcpdump` as an installable package, but `ipkg install tcpdump` cannot find the package.

`ipkg print_architecture`:

```
arch all 1
arch noarch 1
arch mipsbig 10
Successfully terminated.
```

*How do I debug `ipkg install tcpdump` or, alternatively, because you know my architecture, can you point me to a binary?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`tcpdump` isn't listed with the mipsbig arch at the current repo site here: https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/tcpdump

You may need to look at cross-compiling from source:
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/crosscompile

https://github.com/lede-project/source/tree/lede-17.01/package/network/utils/tcpdump

Comment: I appreciate your participation.  Instructions for cross-compilation would be a more accurate answer.  You might want to add to your answer this mipsbinaries github repository:  https://github.com/darkerego/mips-binaries